# how to get participant from registry by email id when identifier is userId

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

i am adding partcipant by creating  transaction name createUser. my participant is identified by userid which i am generating using uuid() randomly

you can see here my user partcipant model and transaction.

```
participant User identified by userId {
 o String userId
 o String name
 o String email 
 o Strign password
 o String isVerified
} 

transaction createUser {
 o String userId
 o String name
 o String email 
 o Strign password
 o String isVerified
}
```

when i use email as identifier, while adding two users with same email id .it throws an error >> user already exist with same email id .
but in my country most of the user does not have email. So i decided to create user with random userId.

the problem is choosing userId as identifier, i am not able to check email id is registered before or not.

my transaction logic code is here for better understanding.

```
const model = 'org.composer.app'

//generating random userId
function uuid() {
    const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1)
    return `${s4()}${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}${s4()}${s4()}`
}

//create User Transaction logic
async function createUser (tx){
  const userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(model+'.user.User')
  const exist = await userRegistry.exists('tx.email')
  if(exist){
    throw new Error("already exist")
  }else{
   const user = getFactory().newResource(model+'.user','User',uuid())
  user.name = tx.name
  user.email = tx.email
  user.password = tx.password
  user.isVerified = tx.isVerified
  await userRegistry.add(user)
 }
}
```

================================

according to comments and answer i am updating post.
i think Email should be partiticpant instead of asset but anyways people are saying it should be asset so i am keeping it as an asset here

```
asset Email identified by email {
o String email
}

participant User identified by userId {
 o String userId
 o String name
 --> Email email 
 o Strign password
 o String isVerified
} 

transaction createUser {
 o String userId
 o String name
 o String email 
 o Strign password
 o String isVerified
}

const model = 'org.composer.app'

//generating random userId
function uuid() {
    const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1)
    return `${s4()}${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}${s4()}${s4()}`
}

//create User Transaction logic
async function createUser (tx){
  const userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(model+'.user.User')
   const emailRegistry = await getAssetRigistry(model+'.email','Email')
   const exist =  emailRegistry.exist(tx.email)
   if (exist){
  throw new Error('Email already exist')
  }else{
  const user = getFactory().newResource(model+'.user','User',uuid())
  user.name = tx.name
  user.email = tx.email
  user.password = tx.password
  user.isVerified = tx.isVerified
   await userRegistry.add(user)
 }
}
```

Comment: you have at least 2 options 1) run a query eg. `query getUserEmail {
  description: "test query"
  statement:
    SELECT org.composer.app.User
      WHERE (email == _$email_ID)
}` and call that query like `return query('getUserEmail', { email_ID: tx.email })` in your function (per the link I sent you) or 2) Maintain a registry of `EmailRegistry` with all existing, registered emails, which you could check with little to no cost (eg `await emailRegistry.exists(tx.email)` etc - ie in a similar fashion to what you did in your code above. Hope this helps.

Comment: 2) continued ..obviously anytime you add a new `User`, you would (in the same `createUser` transaction) add the email to the email Registry (of emails already registered) as the same unit of work? You will know your use case better in any case, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: EmailRegistry i really liked it can i get your email or twitter to connect to you. Now question is email registry should be participant registry or asset registry ?

Comment: EmailRegistry should be **Asset**

Comment: i updated the code lttle bit above in my post according to your answers, is tha okay or need some updation

Answer (score 1):

You can use **query** here:

```
const model = 'org.composer.app'

//generating random userId
function uuid() {
    const s4 = () => Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16).substring(1)
    return `${s4()}${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}-${s4()}${s4()}${s4()}`
}

//create User Transaction logic
async function createUser (tx){

  const userRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(model+'.user.User')

  let mailQuery = buildQuery('SELECT org.composer.app.User WHERE (email == _$inputValue)');

  let assets =  await query(mailQuery, { inputValue: tx.email });

  // if assets.length != 0 that means mail id already exist

  if(assets.length != 0){
    throw new Error("email already exist");
  }else{

   const user = getFactory().newResource(model+'.user','User',uuid());
   user.name = tx.name;
   user.email = tx.email;
   user.password = tx.password;
   user.isVerified = tx.isVerified;
   await userRegistry.add(user);

 }
}
```

Comment: dont you think it will require more computational power for decentralized system like hyperldger. look above comments Paul has suggested to create a registry for email , what do you think about it.